# Backbone forms and custom template

Tags: forms, templates, backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone-forms

It's the first time I work with backbone-forms plug-in and I'm also new at Backbonejs. 
I'm implementing a simple form but the standard backbone-forms' renderd doesn't fit my needs. Reading the [documentation](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms#customising-templates) it comes out that I can set a custom underscore template but I cannot understand how to render the fields' labels.

Can someone help me?

EDIT:

Considering the following:

```
var form = new Backbone.Form({
  template: _.template($('#formTemplate').html()),
  schema: {
    age: { type: 'Number', title: "Age" },
    name: { title: "Name" }
  }
});
```

and the following template:

```
<script id="formTemplate" type="text/html">
    <form>

        <div data-editors="age"><!-- age editor will be added here --></div>
        <div data-editors="name"><!-- nameeditor will be added here --></div>

    </form>
</script>
```

How can I have Backbone-form build automatically labels?

Something like:

```
<label data-label="age"><!-- I wish the label was added here --></label>
<div data-editors="age"><!-- age editor will be added here --></div>
```

computed as:

```
<label for="c1_age">Age</label>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check the label documentation in this link: [Main Attributes - Backbone Forms](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms#main-attributes).

The attribute that you are looking for is the **title**. Description:

*Defines the text that appears in a form field's . If not defined, defaults to a formatted version of the camelCased field key. E.g. firstName becomes First Name. This behaviour can be changed by assigning your own function to Backbone.Form.helpers.keyToTitle.*

So you can use:

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
  schema: {
    // CHECK THE ATTRIBUTE 'title' HERE
    title: { title: 'Title', type: 'Select', options: ['Mr', 'Mrs', 'Ms'] },
    name: { type: 'Text', title: 'Your Name' }
    // ...
  }
}
```

If you don't set the title attribute, the label title will become the camelCased field key.

For templates, you can check [100% custom forms](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms#100-custom-forms), that will follow the same logic, placing the label followed by the input that you want.

**EDIT:**

If you want to build only the label element, I believe this is not possible with backbone-forms. You can find the possible elements at the [Schema Definition](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms#schema-definition). The concept of a label element is to represent a caption for another element in the screen. Please check the [Label Documentation at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label). So, backbone-forms will always place a label, but it'll come with the input.

I think you can just place a label in your template to obtain the behavior that you want.

Comment: Ok, my question needs more clarifications.

Comment: Do you want to build only the label element?

Comment: more or less... see the EDIT in the question

Comment: Edited my answer as well. :)

Comment: So, I should implement by myself something like a post-processing function that after the form is rendered sets the labels, right?

Comment: Actually, you could just place '<label for="c1_age">Age</label>' in the template itself.

Comment: Yeah, sure... but imagine a multi-language application, the title is dynamic and cannot be hardcoded. I think I'll place some data-something attribute and I'll insert the label via jquery.

Comment: If you want the label values to be dynamic you could pass it through your template attributes.

Comment: You can also override the Field template, which will allow you to customise label and editor placement.  Then in your main form template, use data-fields="age" instead of data-editors="age"

Comment: @evilcelery How does one override the Field template?

Comment: Create your own Field prototype and replace the template. Then provide that as the field to your form:
```
var MyField = Backbone.Form.Field.extend({template: ...});
var form = new Backbone.Form({ Field: MyField })
```

Answer (score 0):

As we can see - answer in comment by @evilcelery. For having labels in form with custom template use:

```
<script id="formTemplate" type="text/html">
    <form>
        <div data-fields="age,name"></div>
    </form>
</script>
```